# Creating a variable/column in the same data, for a subset of data using dplyr and mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data in R that looks as follows

```
fact_code style_serial mach_smv
1004      style_1200   0.15
1004      style_1200   0
1004      style_1200   0.30
1004      style_1203   0
1004      style_1203   0.22
1004      style_1203   0.18
1008      style_1120   0.25
1008      style_1120   0.25
1008      style_1120   1
1008      style_1121   0.3
1008      style_1121   0
1008      style_1121   0.6
```

I would like to create a variable, `avg_mach_smv`, to the existing data that takes the average of the variable `mach_smv` when `mach_smv != 0`, and is `NA` otherwise.

An example is given below:

```
fact_code style_serial mach_smv avg_mach_smv
1004      style_1200   0.15     0.225
1004      style_1200   0        NA
1004      style_1200   0.30     0.225
1004      style_1203   0        NA
1004      style_1203   0.22     0.2
1004      style_1203   0.18     0.2
1008      style_1120   0.25     0.5
1008      style_1120   0.25     0.5
1008      style_1120   1        0.5
1008      style_1121   0.3      0.45
1008      style_1121   0        NA
1008      style_1121   0.6      0.45
```

The `Stata` code uses to generate the variable is:

```
bysort fact_code: egen sum_nmachines=sum(nmachines) if ss==1
```

However, I would like to know how the above code or, this variable can be generated using R.

This is the first code that I tried:

```
df <- df %>%
select(fact_code, ss, style_serial, machine_name, process_smv, help, 
mach_smv) %>%
group_by(fact_code, style_serial) %>%
filter(mach_smv != 0) %>%
mutate(avg_mach_smv = mean(mach_smv, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Unfortunately, this is what I am not looking for since it discards those rows where `mach_smv == 0` which is not what I want.

I also tried the following codes below but either I am getting an error or, getting incorrect values:

```
df2 <- df %>%
select(fact_code, ss, style_serial, machine_name, process_smv, help, 
mach_smv) %>%
group_by(fact_code, style_serial) %>%
mutate(avg_mach_smv = if_else(mach_smv != 0, mean(mach_smv, na.rm = TRUE), 
NA_real_))

df2 <- df %>%
select(fact_code, style_serial, mach_smv) %>%
group_by(fact_code, style_serial) %>%
mutate_at(mach_smv != 0, funs(mean(mach_smv, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Any suggestions on how to create the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ifelse` we can check the `mach_smv==0` condition and take `mean` ignoring the 0 values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(fact_code, style_serial) %>%
  mutate(avg_mach_smv = ifelse(mach_smv == 0, NA, mean(mach_smv[mach_smv != 0])))


#   fact_code style_serial mach_smv avg_mach_smv
#       <int> <fct>           <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1      1004 style_1200       0.15        0.225
# 2      1004 style_1200       0           NA    
# 3      1004 style_1200       0.3         0.225
# 4      1004 style_1203       0           NA    
# 5      1004 style_1203       0.22        0.2  
# 6      1004 style_1203       0.18        0.2  
# 7      1008 style_1120       0.25        0.5  
# 8      1008 style_1120       0.25        0.5  
# 9      1008 style_1120       1           0.5  
#10      1008 style_1121       0.3         0.450
#11      1008 style_1121       0           NA    
#12      1008 style_1121       0.6         0.450
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, an alternative using `data.table` you can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(Mean=ifelse(mach_smv!=0,mean(mach_smv[mach_smv!=0]),NA)),
              by=.(fact_code, style_serial)]
```

which returns

```
    fact_code style_serial  Mean
 1:      1004   style_1200 0.225
 2:      1004   style_1200    NA
 3:      1004   style_1200 0.225
 4:      1004   style_1203    NA
 5:      1004   style_1203 0.200
 6:      1004   style_1203 0.200
 7:      1008   style_1120 0.500
 8:      1008   style_1120 0.500
 9:      1008   style_1120 0.500
10:      1008   style_1121 0.450
11:      1008   style_1121    NA
12:      1008   style_1121 0.450
```

Comment: A better alternative imo: `setDT(df)[mach_smv != 0, avg_mach_smv := mean(mach_smv), by = .(fact_code, style_serial)][]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
i1 <-  df$mach_smv != 0
df$avg_mach_smv[i1] <- with(df[i1,], ave(mach_smv, fact_code, style_serial))
df
#   fact_code style_serial mach_smv avg_mach_smv
#1       1004   style_1200     0.15        0.225
#2       1004   style_1200     0.00           NA
#3       1004   style_1200     0.30        0.225
#4       1004   style_1203     0.00           NA
#5       1004   style_1203     0.22        0.200
#6       1004   style_1203     0.18        0.200
#7       1008   style_1120     0.25        0.500
#8       1008   style_1120     0.25        0.500
#9       1008   style_1120     1.00        0.500
#10      1008   style_1121     0.30        0.450
#11      1008   style_1121     0.00           NA
#12      1008   style_1121     0.60        0.450
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(fact_code, style_serial)  %>%
  mutate(avg_mach_smv = case_when(mach_smv !=0 ~ mean(mach_smv[mach_smv != 0]), 
                             TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(fact_code = c(1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1008L, 1008L, 1008L, 1008L, 1008L, 1008L), style_serial = c("style_1200", 
"style_1200", "style_1200", "style_1203", "style_1203", "style_1203", 
"style_1120", "style_1120", "style_1120", "style_1121", "style_1121", 
"style_1121"), mach_smv = c(0.15, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.22, 0.18, 0.25, 
0.25, 1, 0.3, 0, 0.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```